# Intersection of two files based on two columns and one condition

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have two files. One file is tab separated and has content like

```
col1.     col2     col2       col4
Stef.     123       SE        383
Lena      938       Y          X
John      738       T          Y
Stef      827       uq         hd
Stef      81        tt         vv
```

I have another file with just one column:

```
837
123
839
827
```

I want to make a new file which is an interestion of the second column of the first file and the only column of my second text file. But I also want to take into account the first column of the first file.

I know I can do an intersection using:

```
join <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

But I don't know how to specify the its on the first column of the second file and second column of the first file I want to do the intersection based on the value provided which corresponds to the first column of the first file. For example, I only want to the intersection between the two files if first column of the first file is Stef so the resulting file becomes:

```
col1.     col2     col2       col4
Stef.     123       SE        383
Stef      827       uq         hd
```

How can I achieve this using bash and awk. I tried doing it in pandas but because my files are very big it takes a long time to load it on my Jupyter notebook. Insights will be appreciated.

My awk script:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1];next}$2 in A' file2.txt file1.txt > sample.txt
```

Comment: Do you REALLY have a `.` at the end of `col1.` and the first `Stef.`? If not then please fix your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understood correctly the question but you neet to sort the file by the column you want to use as parameter for join:

```
join -1 2 -2 1 <(sort file1 -k2b,2) <(sort file2)

123 Stef. SE 383
827 Stef uq hd
```

EDIT: if you want an specific order:

```
join -1 2 -2 1 <(sort file1 -k2b,2) <(sort file2) | awk -F " " '{print $2 " " $1 " " $3 " " $4}'

Stef. 123 SE 383
Stef 827 uq hd
```

EDIT:  add grep to filter, for example only show Stef. and not Stef (without the dot)

```
join -1 2 -2 1 <(sort file1 -k2b,2) <(sort file2) | awk -F " " '{print $2 " " $1 " " $3 " " $4}' | grep "Stef\."

Stef. 123 SE 383
```

LAST EDIT (I hope)

Looks like you missed the easy part:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1];next}$2 in A' file2.txt file1.txt | grep "^Stef"
```

Comment: But where do you specify that its only Stef for which you want to extract records. I've edited the post to include what I have but I don't know how to include the if statement in there.

Comment: Sorry I edited again

Comment: How about this?

awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1];next}$2 in A' file2.txt file1.txt | grep "Stef"

Comment: Yes both of the solutions work. Thank you!

Comment: Just in case you missed:
| grep "Stef" will filter all the lines do not contains Stef
| grep "^Stef" will filter all the lines do not start with Stef

Comment: None of those scripts would print the header line shown in the expected output and you never need a pipe to grep when you're using awk.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether you want `$1` to match `Stef` exactly:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} (FNR==1) || (($2 in a) && ($1=="Stef"))' file2 file1
col1.   col2    col2    col4
Stef    827     uq      hd
```

or words that start with `Stef`, e.g. `Stef.`:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} (FNR==1) || (($2 in a) && ($1~/^Stef/))' file2 file1
col1.   col2    col2    col4
Stef.   123     SE      383
Stef    827     uq      hd
```